# how to reduce the time complexity of this code?

Tags: graphs, time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, network-analysis

I have a graph `G=(V,E)`. A list of nodes `NODE` subset of `V`. I want to find out all the neighbor nodes of each node in `NODE` and add edge if those neighbors have distance greater than 2. Can anyone here please help me to reduce the time complexity of this code to quadratic time or less.

```
import networkx as nx
import random

G = nx.erdos_renyi_graph(30, 0.05)

node=[]
for j in range(5): 
        node.append(random.randint(1,30))

for i in node:
    lst=list(G.neighbors(i))
    if(len(lst)>1):
         for j in range(len(lst)):
             for k in range(j+1,len(lst)):
                 if(len(nx.shortest_path(G,lst[j],lst[k]))>2):
                     G.add_edge(lst[j],lst[k])
```

Comment: As presented, this looks a [programming problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Check out [stack**overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [CodeReview@SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @greybeard I don't agree.  This is an algorithmic question.  What is the best algorithm to find pair of vertices whose distance exceed 2.

Comment: @PålGD Please see the caption of tag `python`. I think the very same question would be on topic if presented differently.

Comment: I see the tag, but when you put it like that, it seems like the `python` tag is a catfishing mechanism.

Comment: Can you state the problem concisely, in a way that doesn't require me to understand Python code?  I don't know what you mean by "add edge".  When you refer to "distance", I'm not sure which two nodes you are measuring the distance between.  Is it a weighted or unweighted graph?  etc.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/126720/755, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62106126/781723, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/243383/65105.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get quadratic time, do the following:

Let $M = N(\text{NODE})$ be the neighbours of NODE in $G$.

Compute $G' = (G - \text{NODE})^3$, the *2nd [power graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.product.power.html)* of $G$ without the vertices from NODE.

Then you do the following:  For every two vertices $u$ and $v$ in $M$, if $uv \notin E(G')$, add $uv$ to $G$.

This way you don't have to compute `shortest_path` anymore.

Comment: is there any other efficient way of writing those loops so that complexity becomes quadratic time or less @Pål GD

Comment: Yes, if you do it my way, you can do it in quadratic time.  Feel free to upvote (and accept) the answer if you feel that it answers your question.